# How often does xhr.upload.onProgress fire?

Tags: jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I am subscribing to the onProgress event when uploading a file via XHR.  My progress bar is animated (via jQuery) to provide a better visual aesthetic.

onProgress seems to fire very rapidly, so I wondered how often it actually gets fired so that I can somehow devise a process whereby I can throttle responses to this so that I can have one continuously animated progress bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) for throttling the calls to your `onprogress` callback.

Throttling demos: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/throttle/

Your code would look something like this:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = $.throttle(100, function (event)
{
    // update the progress bar
});
```

Answer (score 7):

While extending jQuery can be beneficial; for something this simple extending jQuery is not worth the overhead. An effective solution for limiting function calls could be written as:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
  // limit calls to this function
  if (!this.NextSecond) this.NextSecond = 0;
  if (Date.getTime() < this.NextSecond) return;
  this.NextSecond = Date.getTime() + 1000;

  // this code gets executed at least one second apart from the last time
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`_.throttle(function, wait)`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle)

UnderscoreJS has utilities for throttling functions.

The actual amount `onProgress` get's fired is browser specific so it's best to throttle the actual callback on a time-based solution.